# Insert Query not working (FMDB)

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

Here is the code which I'm using to insert a record into a sqlite table

```
FMDatabase *dataBase = [self openDatabase];
    [dataBase open];
    if ([dataBase open] != YES) {
        NSLog(@"DB Error %d: %@", [dataBase lastErrorCode], [dataBase lastErrorMessage]);
    //VERY IMPORTANT
    }

    BOOL success= [dataBase executeUpdate:@"Insert into CrewUnits (pkCrewUnits,fkUnits,fkAgencyVehicles,fkLookupCodes_PrimaryRole, fkLookupCodes_LevelOfCare, PrimaryUnit) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", pkCrewUnits, fkUnits, fkAgencyVehicle, fkLookupCodes_PrimaryRole, fkLookupCodes_LevelOfCare, [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
    NSLog(success ?@"YES" :@"NO");
     NSLog(@"Error %d: %@", [dataBase lastErrorCode], [dataBase lastErrorMessage]);
   FMResultSet*resultSet= [dataBase executeQuery:@"select * from CrewUnits"];
    NSLog(@"ResultSet : %@", [resultSet resultDictionary]);

    [dataBase close];
```

Database Path

```
- (FMDatabase *)openDatabase
{

    NSLog(@"Open Database");
    NSString *documents_dir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *db_path = [documents_dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"HPSix_05BD.db"]];    // DatabasePath
    FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:db_path];
    if (![db open])
        NSLog(@"Failed to open database!!!!!");
    return db;
}
```

I'm using the same logic to fetch data from table that works fine for me. But I can't insert a record. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Do you get an error or exception? And are pkCrewUnits, fkUnits, fkAgencyVehicle, fkLookupCodes_PrimaryRole, fkLookupCodes_LevelOfCare all objects and not simple types?

Comment: Error 0: not an error

Comment: They  are actually GUID's as sqlite don't support GUID's they are strings. @edwardmp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You are calling `open` three times. Once in `openDatabase` and twice in the code that called it.

   So, have your open routine open the database if it can, but return `nil` if it can't:

   ```
   - (FMDatabase *)openDatabase
   {
       NSLog(@"Open Database");
       NSString *documents_dir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
       NSString *db_path = [documents_dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"HPSix_05BD.db"]];    // DatabasePath
       FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:db_path];
       if (![db open]) {
           NSLog(@"Failed to open database!!!!!");
           return nil;
       }
       return db;
   }
   ```

   Then check that result:

   ```
   FMDatabase *dataBase = [self openDatabase];
   if (!dataBase) {
       // quit; note, no point in checking error message as it only returns meaningful messages if you have an open database
   }
   ```
2. After calling `executeQuery`, you have to call `next`.

   ```
   FMResultSet *resultSet = [dataBase executeQuery:@"select * from CrewUnits"];
   if ([resultSet next]) {
       NSLog(@"ResultSet : %@", [resultSet resultDictionary]);
   } else {
       NSLog(@"No data found");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the problem. You are committing after running the SELECT query.

You have to commit right after the UPDATE query. When you do it like you have now when selecting, the UPDATE query has not been committed and thus will not be returned.

```
[dataBase beginTransaction];
BOOL success= [dataBase executeUpdate:@"Insert into CrewUnits (pkCrewUnits,fkUnits,fkAgencyVehicles,fkLookupCodes_PrimaryRole, fkLookupCodes_LevelOfCare, PrimaryUnit) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", pkCrewUnits, fkUnits, fkAgencyVehicle, fkLookupCodes_PrimaryRole, fkLookupCodes_LevelOfCare, [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
[dataBase commit]; // commit the query
NSLog(success ?@"YES" :@"NO");
NSLog(@"Error %d: %@", [dataBase lastErrorCode], [dataBase lastErrorMessage]);
// now at this point the transaction has been committed and can be selected
FMResultSet*resultSet= [dataBase executeQuery:@"select * from CrewUnits"];
NSLog(@"ResultSet : %@", [resultSet resultDictionary]);
```

Also [according to FMDB docs](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb#data-sanitization):

> The parameters must start with a colon. SQLite itself supports other
>   characters, but internally the Dictionary keys are prefixed with a
>   colon, do not include the colon in your dictionary keys.

Thus this line of code must be rewritten to:

```
BOOL success= [dataBase executeUpdate:@"Insert into CrewUnits (pkCrewUnits,fkUnits,fkAgencyVehicles,fkLookupCodes_PrimaryRole, fkLookupCodes_LevelOfCare, PrimaryUnit) values (:pkCrewUnits,:fkUnits,:fkAgencyVehicles,:fkLookupCodes_PrimaryRole, :fkLookupCodes_LevelOfCare, :PrimaryUnit);", pkCrewUnits, fkUnits, fkAgencyVehicle, fkLookupCodes_PrimaryRole, fkLookupCodes_LevelOfCare, [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
```

Lastly according to the docs you use `next` for looping through the results:

```
while ([resultSet next]) {
    //retrieve values for each record
}
```

Comment: I have tried that too. And my error log is Error 0: not an error

Comment: MENTION what you have tried then and stop wasting peoples time. The documentation specifies this so what you are doing seems wrong

Comment: FWIW, the `?` placeholders in the SQL is fine. FMDB supports the colon-prefixed parameters combined with dictionary of parameters, too, but the OP's original simple `?` placeholders with an array of values is perfectly fine, too (and preferable, IMHO)